# TableView inside the More tab

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I have a series of tabs and the last one is a "more" tab. When you click it, it gives you a list or items. When you select something from the list, it opens a window with a TableView. The tableview rows are populated perfectly, but for some reason when you click the row to get the details, nothing happens.

I am using the same exact code that works in just a regular tab. Why does it not work inside the More tab? I searched and cannot find any examples or any similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's a problem with having an event listener for the rows in your tableview. It would help a lot if you provided code on how you're currently viewing the details for each row.

Given the information provided, try doing something similar to as follows:

```
row.addEventListener('click', function(){
    // logic
})
```